# Replacing string but duplicate part of string

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I have several batch files i need to alter.
looping through the files and replacing works fine.

I just cant figure out how to have a  single line like

```
net use w: \\someserver\someshare
```

replaced by two lines

```
net use w: /delete /yes  
net use w: \\someotherserver\someshare
```

is this at all possible with replace and regular expressions?
Or do i have to store the driveletter in a variable to accomplish this?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible with `-replace`:

```
$yourFilePath = 'PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE'
$content = Get-Content $yourFilePath
$content -replace '^net use (\w): .*', "net use `$1: /delete /yes `n`$0" | Set-Content $yourFilePath
```

The script adds the desired line to your file and uses the particualr drive, but doesn't check, whether the line (`net use drive: /delete /yes`) already exist.

Comment: Thanks, that works great :)  Only needed to add     `r before the     `n to get it on a new line.  Care to explain how the drive letter ended up in $1?

Comment: its because (`\w)` is in parentheses thus captured in `$1` (because its the first capture group. `$0` is the whole regex match

Comment: I'd capture everything up to and including the colon, as it's the same in both commands: ``-replace '^(net use \w:) .*', "`$1 /delete /yes`n`$0"``

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers True, I missed that. You won the regex golf (http://regex.alf.nu/) ;-)